# http and https versions of my site work differently

Tags: http, web, https

Can you tell me how to make the https version of my site work like the http one?

https://www.sorenballard.com/

http://www.sorenballard.com/

https is only partly working.

Thanks
Art

Answer (score 2):

The https doesn't work because within your code you are requesting resources using http.

You need to make sure all the permalinks and resources (images, styles, ...) are also coming from https requests.

As example, change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://sorenballard.com/wp-content/themes/sorenmountain/style.css" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://sorenballard.com/wp-content/themes/sorenmountain/style.css" />
```